# BlackBerry debugging on Mac

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, osx-snow-leopard, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I installed everything necessary to start the development for blackberry on mac but I have an issue. 
I know I cannot use the simulator on Mac so I'm using a Blackberry bold 9870.. I downloaded the debug files for it from the blackberry development site and following the steps at [this site](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23674/Debug_BB_app_debug_pkg_Mac_1427782_11.jsp)

In the steps when I click on debut as > bb device it's not prompting anything to select the folder for the debug files downloaded.

By the way, when I'm clicking on debug it shows me nothing on the IDE and on the mobile a screen with "Attaching debug" that is disappearing quickly, so with no results.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will keep your sanity in check if you do development on Windows. If you are working on Mac, you will need to test directly on the phone. Check this [thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-Simulator-for-Mac-OSX/td-p/766769).

As it is life is difficult. It's better not to spice it up further!

Comment: :D Good, I will switch os! Is there any problem if I remove the licences from Mac and add'em in Windows?

Comment: Could you clarify which licenses are you referring to? Could you please select the this as an accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure. There would be no issues. You can import keys on windows machine.